# Youtube iframe API - hiding controls and related videos not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube

have a project where we're trying to jerry-rig a solution for a kiosk. Trying to make it possible to view the videos but hide all controls and related information so they press a button to play, and another button to go back. I'm currently structuring a video like so:

```
$('#vidPlayer1').on('click', function(){
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    videoId: 'MYVIDEOID',
    controls: 0,
    showinfo: 0,
    autoplay: 0,
    rel: 0,
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
  // Make sure we hide view content.
  hideContent(v1c);
});
```

Supposedly, controls: 0, showinfo: 0, rel:0 should remove all this information, but it's not hiding the information. Is there something I'm missing here? The video views and plays just fine - it's just the additional information is displaying. Thoughts?

Comment: I am also having this issue, did you get around this?
I am getting an error about origin but I doubt its related

Comment: Unfortunately no, I ended up using a jerry rigged solution that didn't involve Youtube. Apologies!

Comment: Damn seems like this is 'intended'

Answer (score 0):

[Video Player Constructors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Example_Video_Player_Constructors)

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onPlaybackQualityChange': onPlayerPlaybackQualityChange,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
      'onError': onPlayerError
    }
  });
}
```